# Connect to ServiceFabric using Azure Automation

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-service-fabric, azure-automation

I am trying to run the following test script using a hybrid runbook worker via Azure Automation:

```
Connect-ServiceFabricCluster -ConnectionEndpoint "the-service-fabric-azure-url" -FindType FindByThumbprint -FindValue "the-thumbprint" -X509Credential -ServerCertThumbprint "the-thumbprint" -StoreLocation CurrentUser -StoreName My -Verbose

$app = Get-ServiceFabricApplication -ApplicationName "fabric:/the-application-name"

Write-Output $app
```

When I run this script locally on my machine, it works. When I run this script using a Powershell session on the VM, it also works.

When I put this script in a runbook and then run the runbook via the hybrid work group (which points to the same VM, since there is only one worker registered to that group), I get an error:

```
Connect-ServiceFabricCluster : An error occurred during this operation. Please check the trace logs for more details. At line:1 char:1 +   
Connect-ServiceFabricCluster -ConnectionEndpoint "my-service-fabric-url... +  

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ +   
CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (:) [Connect-ServiceFabricCluster], FabricException +   
FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateClusterConnectionErrorId,Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Powershell.ConnectCluster
```

**What do I need to configure so that the hybrid group can execute the same script that a local Powershell session can already execute correctly?**

---

Some extra information:

- The ServiceFabric SDK is installed on the VM. Since I can connect from the VM to ServiceFabric via a Powershell session, confirms that the SDK is available on the VM.
- The hybrid group works correctly. If I run a small Powershell script that outputs the local machine name, it returns the name of my Azure VM, so I know it's being run on the machine I want it to run on. Any non-ServiceFabric-related script that I've run has worked without issue.
- I have made sure to install the ServiceFabric certificate on the VM. On the VM, I can browse to the SF explorer website, and I can run the script via a powershell session, so I know the certificate is installed correctly because otherwise that wouldn't work either.
- I have also installed the certificate into the Azure Automation account itself, but that didn't have any effect on the error I'm getting.
- The error mentions to check the trace logs, but I have no idea where that is.
- The Service Fabric nodes and the hybrid runbook worker VM are all on the same virtual network. Since I can connect from the VM to ServiceFabric via a Powershell session, this doesn't seem to be a network issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a certificate location that's based on the user that runs the script (`-StoreLocation CurrentUser -StoreName My`).

You should use a location that can be accessed by (the / any) account that runs the automation instead.

Azure Automation has [built-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Az.Automation/Get-AzAutomationCertificate?view=azps-3.8.0&viewFallbackFrom=azps-3.7.0) support for this, using the `Get-AzAutomationCertificate` command.

More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/shared-resources/certificates).

Comment: I actually managed to solve it by simply installing the certificate for the local machine (instead of the current user), but I'll accept this as the answer as it correctly identifies it was a "different account" kind of issue.

Comment: great, glad I could help